# Do or don't drink the dregs of a hefeweizen?

Tags: hefeweizen

Everything I've read says absolutely do not drink the last quarter inch of a homebrew because it will be terrible. But most hefeweizens instruct you to swirl the last of the bottle before pouring it in. Do I swirl or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because hefeweizens are by style intended to be a cloudy beer. Rolling the bottle, or swirling the last of the pour is common. The yeast is part of the flavor profile too.

Many styles are like this especially if they have adjucts that can settle out in bottle storage.

With bottle conditioned homebrew generally the dregs are yeast from the carbonation phase. If it's intended as a clear beer style then it's best to leave the dregs in the bottle. Drinking it won't hurt you, but may throw a beer out of style if poured wrong.

Comment: So I should swirl?

Comment: Depends. If it's a clear style (dregs bad) pour or drink from the bottle without disturbing the dregs. If it depends on the dregs (dregs good) roll and gently invert to mix when drinking from the bottle, if using a glass pour as normal then swirl the last bit and add to your glass.

Comment: One possible consideration: brewer's yeast is among the contributing factors to gout, so it's probably best to minimize your intake if you're susceptible. (Yes, I know beer itself is a contributing factor, but who wants to give that up?) ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Drink it or don't drink it, because it all depends on your beer palate.

It realy depends on the beer itself. Homebrew could taste like chalk, but it really depends on how it is brewed and if the sediments have dropped to the bottom. This depends on the heat at the time of brewing and how it is stored.

I pour most of the beer into the glass at a 45 degree angle, swirl the last ounce or so around to collect any yeast or other sediment, dump it in the glass and drink it all together. I like the head(foam) of all wheat beer.

I have also rolled the beer on the table before opening it. This allows all of the sediment to float around the bottle. I tilt my cold beer glass about a 45 degree angle and pour the beer slow. Leaving a nice head(foam).

Answer (score 0):

Swirl it around and drink it. It will taste fine, unless your home brew itself tastes terrible. I do it all the time.